# Build failed after updating SDK tools and plays services libraries

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi I've currently updated my SDK tools as well as the other components of my SDK except for the M-preview and the sample files which is currently I won't be using. Now problem is after updating the libraries and syncing the gradle it gives me this error:

```
error: Attribute "track" has already been defined
error: Attribute "thumbTextPadding" has already been defined
error: Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined
error: Attribute "switchPadding" has already been defined
```

and now my app won't build or run due to this values error on which I'm not sure of why it happens. Here's my current gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.felipecsl.quickreturn:library:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

Can someone point out to me on why does this happen? TIA.

Comment: show your attrs.xml file

Comment: what version of build tools are you using?

Comment: @goonerDroid You just saved me! hahaha! Yes I'm using a custom switch and that might be the real problem as it's using same name.

Comment: @OlegOsipenko it's already on my build.gradle. 22, 22.0.1 the most updated one

Comment: just change the attrs for the switch and you are good to go!!

Comment: Hi updated it but now having the problem UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException. The pain of updating. :))

Comment: @goonerDroid hope you can post that as your answer so I can select it as the correct answer. I've already fixed it but still having some issues. :)) Thanks!

Comment: Disable your proguard temporarily for dev builds..the issue might be because you might be using excessive libraries,hence the Dex merger issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it the attributes you are using ie

```
 error: Attribute "track" has already been defined
    error: Attribute "thumbTextPadding" has already been defined
    error: Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined
    error: Attribute "switchPadding" has already been defined
```

might being used by the M-Preview SDK.Just change your attributes of the Switch you are using in the `attrs.xml` file and you are good to go!